# F#: How to iterate through a List of Arrays of Strings (string [] list) the functional way

Tags: arrays, list, loops, f#, iteration

I'm a newbie at F#,
I've got a List that contains arrays, each arrays contains 7 Strings.
I want to loop through the Arrays and do some kind of Array.map later on,

However my problem is that I can't send individual arrays to some other function.

I don't want to use for-loops but focus on the functional way using pipelines and mapping only.

```
let stockArray =
    [[|"2012-03-30"; "32.40"; "32.41"; "32.04"; "32.26"; "31749400"; "32.26"|];
    [|"2012-03-29"; "32.06"; "32.19"; "31.81"; "32.12"; "37038500"; "32.12"|];
    [|"2012-03-28"; "32.52"; "32.70"; "32.04"; "32.19"; "41344800"; "32.19"|];
    [|"2012-03-27"; "32.65"; "32.70"; "32.40"; "32.52"; "36274900"; "32.52"|];]

let tryout =
    stockArray
    |> List.iter;;
```

Output complains about List.iter:

```
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
'string [] list -> 'a' but given a
'('b -> unit) -> 'b list -> unit' 
The type 'string [] list' does not match the type ''a -> unit'
```

When trying Array.iter, same difference:

```
 error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
'string [] list -> 'a' but given a
'('b -> unit) -> 'b [] -> unit' 
The type 'string [] list' does not match the type ''a -> unit'
```

In C# I would simply go about it with a foreach to start treating my arrays one at a time, but with F# I feel real stuck.

Thank you for your help

Comment: List.iter expects a function that it will call for each member of the list, take a look at its signature.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I'm confused with signatures. I'm struggling to grasp what it tells me. So probably that Iter is not what I want because it needs to spit out "Unit"... I need to spit out "string []" right?

Comment: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-signatures/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe operator `|>` is used to write an `f x` as `x |> f`.

The signature of `List.iter` is:

```
action: ('a -> unit) -> list: ('a list) -> unit
```

You give it an action, then a list, and it gives you a *void*.

You can read it thus: when you give `List.iter` an action, its type will be

```
list: ('a list) -> unit
```

a function to which you can pass a list.

So when you write `stockArray |> List.iter`, what you're actually trying to give it in place of an action is your list - that's the error. So pass in an action:

```
let tryout = List.iter (fun arr -> printfn "%A" arr) stockArray
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
let tryout = stockArray |> List.iter (fun arr -> printfn "%A" arr)
```

Comment: Thanks, so List.iter is not exactly what I'm looking for then. In essence, I'd like to input a list of array, and output a list of array. The output arrays must be the date (item[0]) and an int (item[2] - item[3]). Any idea what function is right to use?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, even with the extra comments. Anyway, I think you will finally be able to figure out your needs from this answer.

I have implemented parseDate and parseFloat in such a way that I expect it to work on any machine, whatever locale, with the given data. You may want something else for your production application. Also, how theInt is calculated is perhaps not what you want.

List.iter, as you already discovered, converts data to `unit`, effectively throwing away data. So what's the point in that? It is usually placed last when used in a pipe sequence, often doing some work that involves side effects (e.g. printing out data) or mutable data operations (e.g. filling a mutable list with items). I suggest you study functions in the List, Array, Seq and Option modules, to see how they're used to transform data.

```
open System
open System.Globalization

let stockArray =
    [
        [| "2012-03-30"; "32.40"; "32.41"; "32.04"; "32.26"; "31749400"; "32.26" |]
        [| "2012-03-29"; "32.06"; "32.19"; "31.81"; "32.12"; "37038500"; "32.12" |]
        [| "2012-03-28"; "32.52"; "32.70"; "32.04"; "32.19"; "41344800"; "32.19" |]
        [| "2012-03-27"; "32.65"; "32.70"; "32.40"; "32.52"; "36274900"; "32.52" |]
    ]

type OutData = { TheDate: DateTime; TheInt: int }

let parseDate s = DateTime.ParseExact (s, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

let parseFloat s = Double.Parse (s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

let myFirstMap (inArray: string[]) : OutData =
    if inArray.Length <> 7 then
        failwith "Expected array with seven strings."
    else
        let theDate = parseDate inArray.[0]
        let f2 = parseFloat inArray.[2]
        let f3 = parseFloat inArray.[3]
        let f = f2 - f3
        let theInt = int f
        { TheDate = theDate; TheInt = theInt }

let tryout =
    stockArray
    |> List.map myFirstMap
```

The following is an alternative implementation of myFirstMap. I guess some would say it's more idiomatic, but I would just say that what you prefer to use depends on what you might expect from a possible future development.

```
let myFirstMap inArray =
    match inArray with
    | [| sDate; _; s2; s3; _; _; _  |] ->
        let theDate = parseDate sDate
        let f2 = parseFloat s2
        let f3 = parseFloat s3
        let f = f2 - f3
        let theInt = int f
        { TheDate = theDate; TheInt = theInt }
    | _ -> failwith "Expected array with seven strings."
```

Answer (score 0):

> However my problem is that I can't send individual arrays to some other function

`List.map` and similar functions allow you to do precisely this - you don't need to iterate the list yourself.

For example, this will return just the first element of each array in your list:

```
stockArray
    |> List.map (fun x -> x.[0])
```

You can replace the function passed to List.map with any function that operates on one array and returns some value.